# Caculating probability of acceptance for Simulated Annealing problems

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, probability, simulated-annealing

I am having troubles figuring out how to calculate the probability of acceptance when looking at the corresponding graph below and n-queens problem when shown below. I understand that the calculation will use

> e^((value of next random state - current state)/(the value of T))

I don't understand exactly how this number is used to define the probability of the acceptance or not. Does this just give the probability in the form of 1/(e^(delta/T)) or am I mistaken?

For the graph, the question is to find the probability of going from node F to the selected child node A as far as I know at this point the Delta is -5 and in the problem T = 5 so I would assume that e^((-5)/5) which is .3679, this would be the probability. The other question is the probability of going from F to the selected node of C this would end up with a delta of 25 and then T = 5 also for this situation. The probability for this would be e^((25)/5).

[This is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smPYg.png)

For the queens problem as shown in this link below, it will be going from a state of 6 pairs of attacking queens to 9 pairs of attacking queens. Unless I am counting these values wrong they would create a value of delta = 3. In this situation T = 3 so the value would be e^((3)/3) = e = 2.718

[This is the queens problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrzCI.png)

Comment: If x is the system energy, then the usual definition of probability is actually 1 if x'>x and e^(x' - x) otherwise.  You've left out the first check. That is, you _always_ choose a next state if it will decrease energy. Only when the energy would increase is a probability computed. You use this probability in the algorithm by generating a random real r in [0..1] and testing P <= R .

Comment: aren't you missing a variable for your probability equation, the T variable. so what would my probability be in those 3 different instances?

Comment: the probability  would be then in 1/(e^(delta/t)) correct?

Comment: Sorry yes I left out the division by T.  You're right with the caveat that delta is non-negative (so the probability is at most 1). It's more common to say e^(delta/t) where delta is assumed to be <= 0. This is of course the same thing.

Comment: so, I would say that e^((3)/3) proability would be 1/2.718 which would be a probability of 36.79%?

Comment: e^-3/3 = e^-1 = 1/2.718  Yes. This would be the probability at T=3 of increasing energy by 3.  As temp gets lower, the exponent gets more negative. This means at cooler temps there's less chance to accept states "worse" than current, i.e. that you'll be able to jump out of a local min. That's why T starts large and decreases gradually. You jump out of local mins of ever decreasing size: big valleys initially down to little notches at the end. [Animation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing#/media/File:Hill_Climbing_with_Simulated_Annealing.gif) shows this well.